# how to passing value from a external page to inside a frame?

Tags: php, html

I have a files inside a page , this page  named (mainframe.php)  is a frameset contain two subframes files (file 1 : topframe.php , file 2 bottom frame.php) and i need to pass a value from an external page(file:extarnalpage.php) to inside the frmams(topframe and bottomframe). but I can not do that...and the pages is as the followin:

- mainframe.php

..............................................

- topframe.php

topframe

topframe content

?>

.......................................................

- bottomframe.php

bottomframe

bottomframe content

..................................................

- externalpage.php

bottomframe

bottomframe content

........................................................

my qus is how to get the value of the text from the externalpage.php to topframe.php and bottomframe.php .
thanks

Comment: Are these pages executed asynchronously? Do you have control of all four pages?

Answer (score 1):

What come in mind is sessions.

Sessions are stored on server and it goes something like this:

**to set variables in session:**

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['some_variable_name_1']='some_variable_value_1';
$_SESSION['some_variable_name_2']='some_variable_value_2';
...
$_SESSION['some_variable_name_n']='some_variable_value_n';
?>
```

**to retrieve variables from session on other page:**

```
<?php
session_start();

$some_variable_value_1 = $_SESSION['some_variable_name_1'];
$some_variable_value_2 = $_SESSION['some_variable_name_2'];
...
$some_variable_value_n = $_SESSION['some_variable_name_n'];
?>
```

more on sessions at http://www.php.net/session

But I would really encourage you to leave frames and tables and use css for element positioning - it is so much easier and you get more readable html.